# c# style for private variable using _ or this?

Tags: c#

I would like to know which is a prefer way to refer to a private field in C# code?

Is using an underscore in front of the variable `_` or using `this` is a prefer way?

What is the benefits and disadvantages of these 2 styles?

In code

```
private string _name;

private void getName()
{
     return String.format("{0} - hello", _name);
}
```

or the second method

```
private string name;

private void getName()
{
     return String.format("{0} - hello", this.name);
}
```

I prefer the 2nd method, because it is clearer for me that this variable name is belong to this instance, and I used them extensively in Javascript, but I dont see them used in C#, mostly the first style is prefer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really any rule or even any general recommendation for this. You should pick one way and stick to it, or agree on one if you are in a team.

The advantage of using an underscore over `this` is that it's part of the variable name. You can only access `_name` as `_name`, not as `name`. When you use `this` you can just as well access it as `name` instead of `this.name`.

JavaScript conventions doesn't really translate to C# private members, as there are no private members in JavaScript, and there is no class scope so the only way to access a member is by using `this.`

Answer (score 3):

Typically C# uses the first style under the hood. This is so that private variables are immediately easy to tell apart from properties, wherein most of the time you should be using Properties except when in the code of Properties. The advances in C# have made the need for backing fields even less commonly necessary, as well.

Note that the second style isn't really necessary - the `this` is redundant unless you also have a local variable or parameters named `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Our team had a big wrangle over private member naming conventions: the StyleCop standard is to use `this`, and that is a very good way of distinguishing all members (fields, properties and methods) from non-members, but it does sometimes create name clash with method arguments.

In the end we agreed a compromise on `this` and `_` and wrote a StyleCop rule to enforce this. At the time people on both sides felt a bad compromise had been made, but now the dust has settled I've actually found it very practical.

The underscore makes it easy to access private fields with the guarantee of no name clash and the `this` keeps consistent access.